# How to close SQL connection in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm going to explain the whole situation in case anyone has a better solution than the one I got.

First, these are the technologies I'm using:

> ```
> SQL Server 2012
> Entity Framework 5
> ASP.NET MVC 4
> Repository Pattern for EF5 developed by myself
> ```

I'm getting SQL Server's error 19 (Physical connection does not exists) constantly in some parts of my code. From my research I could see that's me not ensuring the connection is closed after its use. 
The alternatives I could find were:

1. Using the keyword `using`
2. Closing the connection after my action returns

I discarded the first approach because the code is pretty big, so finding every place that uses my context and changing it would be out of reach at this moment.

So I thought about using the second approach, I would just need to create an attribute to decorate my controllers and every time an `action` returned I would ensure the connection is closed/disposed afterwards. That I already know how to do:

```
public class MyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //code to get the current running connection
    }
}
```

My question is: **how can I get the current entity framework connection and close it from my attribute?**

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: These might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285877/closing-connections-explicitly-in-entity-framework and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738582%28v=vs.90%29.aspx. What are you doing that you'll need to close the connection? By default, EF handles that for you.

Comment: @LordALMMa that should be the case, but it's not happening I'd say it's because I'm not using the keyword `using`, but I don't know. BTW I checked all those links before posting the question. My question is how can I get the current open connection at my attribute's level. Thanks.

Comment: @downvoter: what's not clear?

Comment: Where is your context reference: inside the action or within the controller?

Comment: @LordALMMa inside the action, I have a separate project to handle my business logic, but the call is inside the controller.

Comment: From what I know, you can't close it because you simply can't get variable values outside the scope of your method (eg: after it's execution). They exist only inside the scope. After thar, GC will take over, collect them and properly dispose each of them, including your context. What you can try is to properly implement the IDisposable interface on your context and force connection close there. Might help. But I'm pretty sure this is done by EF. You problem seems to be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are instantiated and disposed for each action call by the framework.  You may safely create your entity framework context in the controller's constructor, store it in a field of the controller, and dispose of it in the controllers' `Dispose` method.

Comment: Hi tne, thanks for the answer. The only problem with your approach is that I would need to create my context in my controller, not on my separate library (as it is today). But I'll take a look at it and see how can I create my EF instance in the controller's context. I'll let you know the results. Thanks.

Comment: Not necessarily, a common approach is to use dependency injection techniques to create the context outside the controller. In its most basic form, you accept a context object via a constructor argument for the controller.